# Prove that the sequence $(f(x_n))_{n\geqslant1}$ is Cauchy.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a regulated function. Let $(x_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ be a sequence in $[0,1)$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=1$. Prove that the sequence $(f(x_n))_{n\geqslant1}$ is Cauchy.

I know that the definition of a regulated function is this:

> A function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is a regulated function if $\forall \varepsilon>0$ there is a step function $\varphi:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ such that $\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)-\varphi(x)| <\varepsilon$.

and the definition of a Cauchy sequence is this:

> A sequence $x_n$ is Cauchy if $\forall \varepsilon > 0,\exists N\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}$, $n>N$, $\left|x_m - x_n \right|< \varepsilon $.

But I don't know how to prove a sequence is Cauchy, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a sequence $x_n$ is Cauchy if $∀\epsilon >0,∃ N \in \bf{N}$ such that when $m, n>N, ∣x_m−x_n∣<ε$.

Because $f(x)$ is a regulated function defined on $[0,2]$, for $∀\epsilon >0$, there is a step function $\varphi: [0,2] \rightarrow \bf{N}$ such that ${\text{sup}}_{x\in [0,2]}|f(x)−\varphi(x)|<\epsilon/2$. Specifically, $|f(1) - \varphi(1)|<\epsilon/2$, and ${\text{lim}}_{x\rightarrow 1}|f(x) - \varphi(x)| <\epsilon/2$. As $\varphi(x)$ is a step function,there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\varphi(x) =c \in \bf{R}$ when $x \in (1-\delta,1)$ and $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| = |f(x_1) -c -(f(x_2) -c)| \leq | f(x_1) -c| +| f(x_2) -c) |<\epsilon/2 +\epsilon/2 =\epsilon$ if $x_1,x_2  \in (1-\delta,1)$. As $(x_n) \in [0,1)$ and ${\text{lim}}_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n =1 $, thus Cauchy, $∃ N \in \bf{N}$ such that when  $m, n>N, ∣x_m−x_n| <\delta/2$ and $x_n,x_m  \in (1-\delta,1)$. Consequently, $|f(x_n) - f(x_m)|<\epsilon$. Hence $(f(x_n))$ is Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is regulated if and only if it has RHS limit at $x\in[a,b)$ and LHS limit at $(a,b]$. You can find a proof of the theorem [see 7.4.18](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=zrVtCKA3CO4C&pg=PA393&lpg=PA393&dq=thomae+function+regulated+step+function&source=bl&ots=DTAwajQxiW&sig=bljUjWGPbf9F5xvKHo-1vuh8CQs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ibhLVKXjCJbq8AWUnYHoAw&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=thomae%20function%20regulated%20step%20function&f=false).

In particular, since $f:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a regulated function, and $(x_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ be a sequence in $[0,1)$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=1$. $(f(x_n))_{n\geqslant1}$ must converge to the LHS limit at $x=1$, so it's Cauchy.